# How do you make a table column that never wraps and is auto width?

Tags: html, css

I need to create a two-column full-width table where:

- Column 1 wraps when it needs to
- Column 2 never wraps and fills any empty space

See a visual example here:

[image]

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring this out... here's where I'm up to:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: right;
}

/* Below is arbitrary example CSS, not part of solution */
.container {
  width: 250px;
}
td {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<h4>Example A</h4>
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class='col-1'>Not much text</td>
      <td class='col-2'>Column 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h4>Example B</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class='col-1'>This has a lot of text that wraps</td>
        <td class='col-2'>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Notice that col-1 isn't expanding because of the `width: 60%` on `col-2`. If I remove that, then `col-1` defaults to taking up all the space, which breaks `Example B`.

I can get this working with flexbox, but then the columns don't line up properly when `col-1` wraps... so I think it needs to remain a table.

Any ideas would be massively appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: I don't think what you are asking is resolvable. In my opinion, simply you should state a predefined fixed width for a column or leave it `auto` to change according to contents with an inner browser's algorithm. In this case, you can have for example two css classes, one for when text is small and the other one for when the text is long.

Comment: It seems like grid solution is a valid answer, which both to my understanding fulfill original tasks criteria. If you have a niche situation where both don't work, please elaborate on your problem. Tables should be used only for tables, forget them as styling solutions, they are have been killed for a reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS grid should do it:

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  width: 250px;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.col-2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: right;
}

p {
  background: hotpink;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h4>Example A</h4>

<div>
  <p class='col-1'>Not much text</p>
  <p class='col-2'>Column 2</p>
  <p class='col-1'>row2</p>
  <p class='col-2'>Column 2</p>
</div>

<h4>Example B</h4>
<div>
  <p class='col-1'>This has a lot of text that wraps</p>
  <p class='col-2'>Column 2</p>
  <p class='col-1'>row2</p>
  <p class='col-2'>Column 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add "white-space: nowrap" to td because of this it will never wraps and it will take is auto width.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: right;
}

/* Below is arbitrary example CSS, not part of solution */
.container {
  width: 250px;
}
td {
  background: lightblue;white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<h4>Example A</h4>
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class='col-1'>Not much text</td>
      <td class='col-2'>Column 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h4>Example B</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class='col-1'>This has a lot of text that wraps</td>
        <td class='col-2'>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: but this breaks the with, width of second table is more than 250!

Comment: Then you can try with giving width to the td.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPIqH.png)

**Is this The output You are looking For?**

if this is it then i simply as you said i removed width but col-2 took up the blank space as required

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 5px!important;
  text-align: right;
}

/* Below is arbitrary example CSS, not part of solution */
.container {
  width: 250px;
}
td {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h4>Example A</h4>
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class='col-1'>xx</td>
      <td class='col-2'>Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='col-1'>T</td>
      <td class='col-2'>Column 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h4>Example B</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class='col-1'>This has a lot of text that wraps</td>
        <td class='col-2'>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='col-1'>xx</td>
        <td class='col-2'>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this css works fine in your specific html code, it is not working as expected when I copy it to PO's html code. However, I can't figure it out why either it works with your html and why it is not working with PO's html example.

Comment: It might be because there might be another portion of the block of css for same class which has more priority than the css given above so it might be overwriting the design layout.

Comment: Thank you Rose! However, this doesn't actually solve the problem. The only reason it appears to work is because the text inside the first column has been changed from "Not much text" to "xx".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a flexbox approach to consider:

```css
.table {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  height: 50px;
}

.col-2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.col-2 .col {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

/* Below is arbitrary example CSS, not part of solution */
.container {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<h4>Example A</h4>
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="column col-1">
      <p class='col'>Row 1</p>
      <p class='col'>Row Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column col-2">
      <p class='col'>Column 2</p>
      <p class='col'>Column 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h4>Example B</h2>
    <div class="table">
      <div class="column col-1">
        <p class='col'>Automatically wraps when there is a lot of text</p>
        <p class='col'>Row Two</p>
        <p class='col'>Row Three</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column col-2">
        <p class='col'>Column 2</p>
        <p class='col'>Column 2</p>
        <p class='col'>Column 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It does require a height to be set on the `.col` or else the rows won't be of equal height. A CSS grid is probably the way to go though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.col-1{width:100%;white-space: nowrap;}
</style    
<h4>Example A</h4>
    <div class="container">
    <table>
       <tr>
         <td class='col-1'>Not much text</td>
         <td class='col-2'>Column 2</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
    
      <h4>Example B</h2>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td class='col-1'>This has a lot of text that wraps</td>
            <td class='col-2'>Column 2</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is short example by using just **bootstrap4** flex property

Complete running Example: [here](https://www.codeply.com/p?starter=Bootstrap%204)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h3> Sample1 </h3>

<div class="container py-2">
    <div class="d-flex border">
        <div class="pl-4 w-25 d-flex nowrap justify-content-center">Short text line1 </div>
        <div class="pr-4 d-flex flex-grow-1 border  justify-content-end"> Short text line2 </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h3> Sample2 </h3>
<div class="container py-2">
    <div class="d-flex ">
        <div class="w-25 d-flex nowrap">long text long text long textlong text long textlong text long textlong textt</div>
        <div> Short text </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use bootstrap to solve this. make grid with class as (col-md-6 + col-md-6). this will fix the size of both columns to 50% and will not exceed no matter how much the content is.

Answer (score -1):

```
<h4>Example A</h4>
<div class="container">
<table>
   <tr>
     <td class='col-1'  style="white-space: nowrap;">Not much text</td>
     <td class='col-2'>Column 2</td>
   </tr>
  </table>

  <h4>Example B</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class='col-1' style="white-space: nowrap;">This has a lot of text that 
            wraps</td>
        <td class='col-2'>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it